# Routes are being regarded as children of current route when used on a page

Tags: angular, typescript

I noticed that when I add links to a page, which the component for that page has a registered route, the new route is just added onto the end of current page's route as if it were a child route.  For example, When I'm on my **home page**, which has a route of `/home` and I click the link for the **getting started page** which has a route of `/getting-started`, the path I see in the address bar of my browser is `/home/getting-started`.  However when clicking links with the same routes in my **navbar-component** which exists outside of the `router-outlet` it navigates to the correct route as expected.  I don't recall this ever being an issue nor have I been able to find anything in Angular's documentation saying we should do something different when a link to a route exists on a component with its own registered route so why is this happening?

The objects I pass into my components that contain data for navigation look like this

```
export interface Link{
    id: string;
    title: string;
    path?: string;
    subLinks?: Link[];
}
```

So my component will look something like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterLink
    ],
    // template, styles, etc.
})

export class MyComponent{

    @Input() LinkData! : Link;
    // other code

}
```

Then in my template I'll basically do this

```
<li [routerLink]="LinkData.path">{{LinkData.title}}</li>
```

I do this both in my **navbar-component** and on my pages, so why does it work properly when used outside of a page but treat the route like a child route by default when used on a page and how do I stop it from doing that?

Here's a simple [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yozhq6?file=src%2Fpages%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html) that shows exactly what I mean.  If you click the links up top you can see the routes change, if you click the links on the **home page** it goes to the **404 page** and if you look at the route it will be `home/products` and `home/about` rather than `/products` or `/about`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with the code and trying different things it turns out for some reason we need to add a `/` to the beginning of our paths to make it go to the expected page rather than regarding it as a child route.  So I did this in my template

```
<li [routerLink]="LinkData.path">{{'/'+LinkData.title}}</li>
```